# How to delete a specific append child using remove child?

Tags: javascript, css

Using Javascript I programmed a simple checklist, where the user inputs his list and then there is a yellow button with every child, by clicking this yellow box it deletes a specific div, but unfortunately, it deletes with an order from the top of the list to the bottom but what I want it to do is to delete its own div, that's all.

```
function Gen() {
    var c = document.getElementById("inp1").value;


    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.style.background = "#3498DB";
    div1.style.padding = "0.5rem";
    div1.setAttribute("class", "d-flex justify-content-between");
    div1.setAttribute("id", "div1");


    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    p1.setAttribute("class", "font-y");
    p1.style.padding = "0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem";
    p1.style.margin = "0rem";

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.setAttribute("id", "div2");
    div2.style.width = "1rem";
    div2.style.height = "1rem";
    div2.style.background = "yellow";
    div2.setAttribute("onclick", "Rem()");

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.style.margin = "1rem";
    li.setAttribute("id", "li");

    li.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(p1);
    div1.appendChild(div2);

    p1.innerHTML = c;

    document.getElementById("addr").appendChild(li);
    return false;
}
```

by pressing div2 it should delete div1, but its own div1 not the one above it.

Comment: please upload your sample code to codepen/ jsfiddle or codesandbox

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: in that manner, it can replicate the situation easier and faster!

Comment: https://codepen.io/yazeed-zaid/pen/JjYoqEm here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in place of

```js
div2.setAttribute("onclick", "Rem()");
```

use:

```js
div2.onclick = () => li.remove();
```

This uses the `li` variable instead of trying to select `<li>` element.